# Parallel insertion to map

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I wanted to create a map ascribing pairs of integers vectors of integers. My purpose is to do it in parallel way. To ensure that I am not trying to push_back at the same time to the same memory entity (by multiple threads), the second coordinate of map's key pairs is responsible for the current thread number. I encountered, however, problems. It seems that some of the values are not inserting properly. Instead of getting 10 values all together, I get always less (sometimes 9, sometimes 8, 6, etc.)

```
map<pair<int, int>, vector<int> > test;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {
        test[make_pair(i % 3, omp_get_thread_num())].push_back(i);
    }
}
```

I have also tried `test.at(make_pair(i % 3, omp_get_thread_num())).push_back(i)` and it didn't work either. In this case, however, the execution interrupted with an exception.

I thought that `#pragma omp for` distributes the `for` loop into disjoint subsequences of (0,...,9) so that there shouldn't be problem with my code... I am a bit confused. Could someone explain this issue to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because a map is not thread safe (nor is a vector, but this part is not threaded). You have to add mutex, use lock-free containers or prepare your map first.

In this case, start on a single thread by creating all your entries.

```
#pragma omp single
for (int i = 0;i < 3;++i)
{
for (int j = 0;i < 8;++j)
{
    test.insert(make_pair(make_pair(i, j), vector<int>()));
}
}
```

Then do your parallel for (add a barrier).

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the standard library containers are not thread safe.
The appropriate solution for this case is to initialize n-maps (one for each thread) and than join them at the end.

As stated prior, using a mutex (and making access to the map safe) would be a valid solution, however it would also result in worse performance. As every time the map would be accessed each thread would have to wait on the mutex unlocking the data.

It should be noted that a size of 10 is not sufficient to make multithreading worth it, using multiple-threads here would most likely degrade performance.

```
map<pair<int, int>, vector<int> > test[8];
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0;i < large_number; i++)
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_id();
        test[thread_id][make_pair(i % 3, omp_get_thread_num())].push_back(i);
    }
}
#pragma omp barrier 

map<pair<int,int>, vector<int>> combined; 
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) 
    combined.insert(test[i].begin(), test[i].end());
```

Comment: Here, you are copying the vectors at the end, but you can just move them. This pattern is just one of the appropriate solutions, not the appropriate one.

Comment: Sure, there are multiple ways to solve any problem. However using a mutex and using thread-safe containers is not a viable solution as they will degrade performance. (As each thread will have to wait on each access, which in turn will make it worse than the sequential implementation). I considered this the "appropriate" solution as its a common pattern in multi threaded algorithms.

Yes moving would be more optimal.

Comment: Creating the vectors beforehand is just as efficient.

Comment: But what about the code: map<pair<int,int>, vector<int>> combined; 
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) 
    combined.insert(test[i].begin(), test[i].end()); ? This isertion is done in linear way, so I end up with linear insertion to my destination map and I wanted to avoid this with parallel processing...